# Запись звука в Linux

Tags: аудио, звукозапись, linux

Столкнулся с проблемой при записи звука на ноутбуке:
при записи со встроенного микрофона всё записывается отлично.
Когда подключаю микрофон (или выход микшера) — слышен только шум.

Пробовал записывать с помощью `rec` из пакета sox и `arecord`

Answer (score 2):

В консоли команда `alsamixer`, посмотрите настройки.